# Windows 10: intermittent black screen flashing with HDMI splitter

Tags: windows, windows-10, mac, hdmi, connection

I'm running Windows 10 on my Mac Mini using Bootcamp.

I bought myself a HDMI splitter so that I could connect both my Mac and my PS3 to my Dell monitor.

The switcher works fine when I'm running MacOS... but when I switch to Windows I keep getting these occasional black screens flashing intermittently. I removed the HDMI splitter and the screen started working normally again.

Is there a way to fix this by changing some of the settings in Windows 10? Or might I need to try a different splitter or just use two different types of cables? (e.g. displayport for my Mac and HDMI for my playstation)

Comment: Have you tried using the HDMI ports the other way round: where the Mac is plugged in, swap that for the Windows one, and vice versa, to see if the problem is with one port of the splitter? Where does the PS3 come in to it?

Comment: I dont think I tried switching them with Windows actually... but come to think of it, the switcher didn't work properly with my PS3 either (when I was trying to switch between my PS3 and my Mac) ... as I found I had to unplug the HDMI and plug it back in again in order for my monitor to output my PS3 onscreen — maybe the splitter itself is just really poor quality!